# TFS 2017 release management artifact files from version control

Tags: tfs

I would like to access some files from source control (tfvc) while release management.
The sources I found are either build (type "Build") and the whole source tree (type "Team Foundation Version Control").

The type "Team Foundation Version Control" seems to match, but it is not allowed to select sub folder, e.g. "$/MyApp/branches/V2/scripts".

Do I need to create an artifact for the script files?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of linking in a separate repository, I'd strongly recommend either publishing them as a build artifact (as the other answer mentions) or publishing them as a versioned NuGet package.

The reason is because everything that goes into a deployment should be versioned together. Scripts that are changing out of sync with everything else can cause abrupt deployment failures for unknown reasons. Let's say you linked those scripts in as an artifact and started a deployment along your pipeline from Dev -> Production. Dev deployment is fine. QA deployment is fine. Staging deployment is fine. Production deployment... fails? Because of an error in the scripts?

Whoops, someone committed a change to those scripts and introduced a bug. But the scripts weren't versioned, so you had no way of guaranteeing that the scripts being used in prior stages were the same as the scripts being used in your production stage.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your source code as a artifact in your build process. Use the "Publish Artifact" step to publish your source code in Tfs or on a unc path. After that release management downloads your artifacts as the first step.