# How to link subfolder in version control as artifact in release management

Tags: tfs, release-management, alm

Related to [TFS 2017 release management artifact files from version control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44163392/tfs-2017-release-management-artifact-files-from-version-control)

I'm asking a new question because I believe I have an edge case the answers don't directly address and I don't want to derail that OP. Specifically, how do I allow an independent, offsite team building required supporting scripts in a separate TFS Team Project supply their scripts as an artifact in the Release definition of a separate TFS Team Project? The separate team projects are built by independent customers and we are not allowed to append content to their source control. Further, updates to the scripts must automatically spread to all Release definitions using them on the TFS.

We have about 40 team projects in TFS all running on different schedules. A separate operations team handles all build and release management tasks in TFS.

Because of the constant bouncing between team projects and because ops also wanted to use the version control and work item tracking features in TFS, we created a separate team project for them to store scripts, installers, and license files. These are referenced in other projects' RM tasks for automatic installation/execution. There is also a separate version control folder tree for tracking project specific scripts - like this:

- Common
- Applications

  - App1
  - App2
    ...
  - App43

This makes it significantly easier for them to manage their scripts and associate them with work items themselves without having to shuffle across all the other team projects. The dev teams do not have access to the ops project.

However, when linking a version control artifact in RM from their project, it will only bind to the root and appears to copy the entirety of the version control structure to the agent, even though most of this content is not relevant to the app being deployed.

Is there a way to add specific, not all, folders from their project in version control as artifacts to a release definition in a separate project? We have our QA release start the process to production and it pulls in the artifacts from the ops project and the project being released. All subsequent releases reuse the artifacts that succeeded in the QA build instead of going back to the server for new versions of the artifacts.

Build definitions don't let us pick workspace paths outside of the team project so I don't see a way to pull in their scripts in a build step, either.

Is there a way to do this? How are other organizations handling this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TFS 2017 release management artifact files from version control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44163392/tfs-2017-release-management-artifact-files-from-version-control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate Daniel's answer and I believe what he is stating is best practice. However, I believe I found a more direct technical answer to my question through the use of additional repositories.

Release Management allows you to reference Git repos and branches independently, like I had originally hoped to do with folders under the TFVC repo already in a separate project. In this way, we configured the TFVC repo to handle large binaries (installers), license files, etc. which we version and put in a Team Project Nuget feed for reference from RM. To address the folder issue, we created separate Git repos for our operations team project in the same TFS project. Like this:

- Binaries (TFVC-based repo)
- Git Repositories

  - CommonDeploymentScripts
  - Environment Scripts
  - App1 Scripts
  - App2 Scripts
  - etc.

This way TFS RM from any other project can be configured to pull in any one or multiple of these repos as artifacts for use by the agents, bringing down only those scripts that were placed in them.

Also, the ops team doesn't have to cross reference app-specific scripts while bouncing around in a bunch of independent team projects. Note: Daniel is right when he says app-specific stuff should really be versioned and stored with the app project itself. However, some environments may not yet have that luxury so this can fill that need.

RM lets you reference branches under a single Git repo as well so this might be overkill. However, we didn't like the idea of branches under a repo not really having any business ever being merged up into the master - felt like too much room for error.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The same answer I provided in the other answer applies here: Don't. Publish them as NuGet packages or as separate build artifacts; a release definition can have multiple artifacts linked to it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @DanielMann. Publishing the scripts as separate nuget packages seems very unpleasant. Every update for any script in a given package would result in needing to build a new package and upload it to TFS before going through all RM definitions in all 43 team projects to update the package version references to the latest common script libraries. I can see it for specialized scripts but I'm not making the connection for common ones used across projects. Builds won't allow artifacts from different projects in the collection. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: +1 for providing best practices - thank you. However, I added a separate answer that provides a more direct solution to the problem.